# Extract text between strings

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have scraped the text of some legislative speeches. To clean the text, I would like to extract the text following the name of the politician (contained in another column) and preceding the name of the next politician.

The latter is usually a two-word string uppercase, but sometimes it is only one ("PRESIDENTE") or more than two words (always uppercase). In some cases there is one match, in some others there are multiple matches.

My goal would be to create a variable (tetx_match) which includes the text following the matched pattern in `name_surname` (e.g. for the first row in the MWE it would be "Lorem ipsum. amet."). Thanks a lot for your help.

```
    df <- data.frame(name_surname = c("ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE", "ELVIRA SAVINO", "DONATELLA AGOSTINELLI"),
                 text_col = c("ELVIRA SAVINO. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE, dolor sit. ELVIRA SAVINO. amet. ROSARIA BINDI. consectetur adipiscing", 
                              "ELVIRA SAVINO. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE, dolor sit. ELVIRA SAVINO. amet. ROSARIA BINDI. consectetur adipiscing",
                              "DONATELLA AGOSTINELLI. Chiedo di parlare. PRESIDENTE. Ne ha facoltà, sempre per due minuti. DONATELLA AGOSTINELLI. Signora Presidente, 
                              anche io intervengo per una sollecitazione della risposta ad una interrogazione presentata, a cui ancora non abbiamo ricevuto risposta. 
                              Con atto n. 4-00324 del 29 aprile 2013, la sottoscritta ha chiesto. PRESIDENTE. La ringrazio."), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df  %>%
  mutate(
    text_match = str_extract_all(text_col, 
                                 str_c("(?<=", 
                                       name_surname,
                                       "[.,]?\\s).*?(?=[A-Z]{3,})")
    ))
```

Comment: Please do not include other ppl's code trying to sell it as if it were yours. If you use it then give them credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-liner solution. The 'trick' here is to string together (`str_c`) the values in the vector `name_surname` with the syntactic ingredients of a look-behind expression `(?<=...)` and to precisely `str_extract_all` only the text following the look-behind, with the text to extract defined as `[^.]+`, a negative character class allowing any character occurring one or more times **except the period**:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    text_match = str_extract_all(text_col, str_c("(?<=", name_surname,"\\.?\\s)[^.]+")))
#   name_surname                                                                                                            text_col
# 1 ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE ELVIRA SAVINO. Lorem ipsum. ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE dolor sit. ELVIRA SAVINO. amet. ROSARIA BINDI. consectetur adipiscing
# 2     ELVIRA SAVINO ELVIRA SAVINO. Lorem ipsum. ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE dolor sit. ELVIRA SAVINO. amet. ROSARIA BINDI. consectetur adipiscing
#   text_match
# 1         dolor sit
# 2 Lorem ipsum, amet
```

**EDIT**:

If you have long strings involving punctuation in between the names, that complicates things but it's still possible:
The new solution involves not only the above-mentioned look-behind but also a look-ahead `(?=\\s[A-Z]{2,})`, i.e., an instruction to match (and extract) only if there are a whitespace and two or more upper-case letters to the right. The text you want to extract is now expressed as `.*?`. i.e., match any combination of characters but do it lazily - only up until the first match.

New data:

```
df <- data.frame(name_surname = c("ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE", "ELVIRA SAVINO"),
                 text_col = c("ELVIRA SAVINO. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE, dolor sit. ELVIRA SAVINO. amet. ROSARIA BINDI. consectetur adipiscing", 
                              "ELVIRA SAVINO. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE, dolor sit. ELVIRA SAVINO. amet. ROSARIA BINDI. consectetur adipiscing"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

New solution:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    text_match = str_extract_all(text_col, 
                                 str_c("(?<=", 
                                       name_surname,
                                       "[.,]?\\s).*?(?=\\s[A-Z]{2,})")
                                        ))
       name_surname
1 ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE
2     ELVIRA SAVINO                                                                                                                    
    text_col
1 ELVIRA SAVINO. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE, dolor sit. ELVIRA SAVINO. amet. ROSARIA BINDI. consectetur adipiscing
2 ELVIRA SAVINO. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE, dolor sit. ELVIRA SAVINO. amet. ROSARIA BINDI. consectetur adipiscing
                         text_match
1                        dolor sit. 
2  Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum., amet.
```

**EDIT 2**:

```
df  %>%
  mutate(
    # remove PRESIDENTE speech:
    text_col = str_remove_all(text_col, "PRESIDENTE.*?(?=[A-Z]{2,})|\\n\\s{1,}"),
    text_match = str_extract_all(text_col, 
                                 str_c("(?<=", 
                                       name_surname,
                                       "[.,]?\\s).*?(?=\\s[A-Z]{2,})")
    ))
           name_surname
1     ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE
2         ELVIRA SAVINO
3 DONATELLA AGOSTINELLI
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    text_col
1                                                                                                                                                                                          ELVIRA SAVINO. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE, dolor sit. ELVIRA SAVINO. amet. ROSARIA BINDI. consectetur adipiscing
2                                                                                                                                                                                          ELVIRA SAVINO. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE, dolor sit. ELVIRA SAVINO. amet. ROSARIA BINDI. consectetur adipiscing
3 DONATELLA AGOSTINELLI. Chiedo di parlare. DONATELLA AGOSTINELLI. Signora Presidente, anche io intervengo per una sollecitazione della risposta ad una interrogazione presentata, a cui ancora non abbiamo ricevuto risposta. Con atto n. 4-00324 del 29 aprile 2013, la sottoscritta ha chiesto. PRESIDENTE. La ringrazio.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             text_match
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           dolor sit. 
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum., amet. 
3 Chiedo di parlare., Signora Presidente, anche io intervengo per una sollecitazione della risposta ad una interrogazione presentata, a cui ancora non abbiamo ricevuto risposta. Con atto n. 4-00324 del 29 aprile 2013, la sottoscritta ha chiesto.
```

**EDIT 3**:

In case the previous solution is hard to parse due to complex regex patterns, here's an alternative solution with less complex regex patterns and `separate_rows` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df  %>%
  # split strings between speech and speaker name:
  separate_rows(text_col, sep = "(?<=\\.)\\s(?=[A-Z]{2,})") %>%
  # filter those speakers that are in `name_surname`:
  filter(str_detect(name_surname, str_extract(text_col, "[A-Z]+\\s[A-Z]+"))) %>%
  # extract speech:
  mutate(text_col = str_extract(text_col, "(?<=[A-Z]{2,10}[,.]\\s).*$")) %>%
  # for each speaker...:
  group_by(name_surname) %>%
  #... string speech together:
  summarise(text_match = str_c(text_col, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  # re-join with `df`:
  left_join(df, .)
```

Data: Note that I've removed the line breaks as I would assume they are not included in OP's actual data (if they are, the code can be adapted):

```
df <- data.frame(name_surname = c("ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE", "ELVIRA SAVINO", "DONATELLA AGOSTINELLI"),
                 text_col = c("ELVIRA SAVINO. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE, dolor sit. ELVIRA SAVINO. amet. ROSARIA BINDI. consectetur adipiscing", 
                              "ELVIRA SAVINO. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. ROCCO BUTTIGLIONE, dolor sit. ELVIRA SAVINO. amet. ROSARIA BINDI. consectetur adipiscing",
                              "DONATELLA AGOSTINELLI. Chiedo di parlare. PRESIDENTE. Ne ha facoltà, sempre per due minuti. DONATELLA AGOSTINELLI. Signora Presidente, anche io intervengo per una sollecitazione della risposta ad una interrogazione presentata, a cui ancora non abbiamo ricevuto risposta. Con atto n. 4-00324 del 29 aprile 2013, la sottoscritta ha chiesto. PRESIDENTE. La ringrazio."), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have forgotten to say that the texts I want to extract are quite long, with periods in between. So my match should not stop at the first period but at the first uppercase text. Moreover, in some cases name_surname is followed by a comma instead of a period. Do you know how I can deal with these issues? I have updated the MWE.

Comment: Have updated solution - better?

Comment: Thanks again. In theory yes, but unfortunately in practice it does not capture some of the second matches. I hope it is ok, I have updated my MWE.

Comment: Have updated again. Works now?